# How to create a dropdown in Xamarin.Forms that displayes different content per item?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

How am i going to create a dropdown that displays different content depending on the selected item? For example, there are 3 items on a dropdown namely Chart1, Chart2 and Chart3. When i choose Chart1 it should display a Pie Chart. When i choose Chart2 it should display a Bar Grap. When i choose Chart3 it should display a Line Graph. Is that even possible to do? Thank you.

Comment: Atleast post what you tried before while posting any question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have a way to create your charts?
If not there are plenty of 3rd party options out there for charting.

To have the three separate views in the one page as you are trying to do
all you would need to do is create three separate `ContentView` with your three different charts. Use a `RelativeLayout` or an `AbsoluteLayout` to lay the three `ContentView` over the top of each other.

I'll assume you are using a `Picker` control as your drop down.
if so then just use the `picker.SelectedIndexChanged` event to change the visibility of each of the chart `ContentView` according to which option was selected

Comment: Can you pls tell me how to create a dropdown properly? I'm having trouble creating one. Thank you Sir.

Comment: a `Picker` would be your best option. You could also use a `ListView` but that would be a bit more extra work.

Comment: Set up a Picker by adding the chart titles to the `picker.Items`. Then set up an event handler for the `picker.SelectedIndexChanged` event to change the visibility of the chart contentviews

Comment: I used a Picker to create a dropdown and code it in my .xaml.cs file. Is that the proper way to doing it or there's a way i can code it in my .xaml? Does it matter anyway?

Comment: it sounds like you are on the right path, and yes for your case that would be the best way of doing it.